# Scan DynamoDB table for results from the current month using PHP

Tags: php, string, date, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table in AWS DynamoDB, and every item in this table has a String-type "date" attribute, which contains the date when the specific item was created. The date in this attribute is being saved in this format: `dd/mm/YYYY`.

What I want to do is to scan this table, and get all of the results from the current month. I also want to do 2 more individual scans. One for results from the last month (for example, now it is July, so I want to get results from June), and from 2 months ago (for example, I want to get all the results from May).

In the DynamoDB PHP SDK documentation, they are demonstrating a scan, and in the example they are filtering the scan according to an attribute called "time" using this code:

```
'time' => array(
    'AttributeValueList' => array(
        array('N' => strtotime('-15 minutes'))
    ),
    'ComparisonOperator' => 'GT'
)
```

So I thought that I could replace `-15 minutes` with `-1 month`, but the problem with it is that, as you can see in the code above, the "time" attribute is a Number-type, and not String-type, so I can't perform this action.

What can I do to get results only from the current month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store data in `yyyy/mm/dd` format you can [use](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) `begin_with` function to filter your data:

> begins_with ( sortKeyName, :sortkeyval ) - true if the sort key value
>   begins with a particular operand. (You cannot use this function with a
>   sort key that is of type Number.) Note that the function name
>   begins_with is case-sensitive.

Otherwise I don't see how it is possible on data of this format.

Another option is to convert it into Unix timestamps and then you can use <,<=,>,>= or `between` operators